# Elasticsearch querying alias with routing giving partial results

Tags: elasticsearch

In an effort to create multi-tenant architecture for my project.
I've created an elasticsearch cluster with an index 'tenant'

> "tenant" : {
>       "some_type" : {
>         "_routing" : {
>           "required" : true,
>           "path" : "tenantId"
>         },

Now,

I've also created some aliases -

```
"tenant" : {
"aliases" : {
  "tenant_1" : {
    "index_routing" : "1",
    "search_routing" : "1"
  },
  "tenant_2" : {
    "index_routing" : "2",
    "search_routing" : "2"
  },
  "tenant_3" : {
    "index_routing" : "3",
    "search_routing" : "3"
  },
  "tenant_4" : {
    "index_routing" : "4",
    "search_routing" : "4"
  }
```

I've added some data with tenantId = 2

After all that, I tried to query 'tenant_2' but I only got partial results, while querying 'tenant' index directly returns with the full results.

Why's that?

I was sure that routing is supposed to query all the shards that documents with tenantId = 2 resides on.

Answer (score 0):

When you have created aliases in elasticsearch, you have to do all operations using aliases only. Be it indexing, update or search.

Try reindexing the data again and check if possible (If it is a test index, I hope so).

Remove all the indices.

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/' # Warning:!! Dont use this in production.
                                  Use this command only if it is test index.
```

Create the index again. Create alias again. Do all the indexing, search and delete operations on alias name. Even the import of data should also be done via alias name.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, an alias is supposed to a virtual concept. Isn't it supposed to be a shortcut to using the original Index using the routing key ?

Comment: It is a shortcut to part of original index, not the entire index.

Comment: Becoz as per your question, I understand that you haven't indexed using alias. In that case as @javanna answered the data can be in any shard. So, I suggested a reindex. If you have done previously using alias index itself its not required.

Comment: btw, the strangest thing happened, I've created a new alias with deleting the old one, and the old aliases "magically" started to work again. Any idea why ?

Comment: Its really difficult to say why it happened like that with the available data(atleast for me). I guess we need to know your mapping, the way you created your old aliases, the way you deleted them, the way you created the new alias, did the old alias really got deleted?(was that verified),the names of new and the old alias...Too many questions, but it would be helpful if we have these answers before we start digging into the reason...

Comment: the old alias was not deleted! I only added another alias with a different name and then the old one magically happened.

The mapping is irrelevant, the only thing you should know is that there's mapping for tenantId field

I can't really reproduce the phenomenon that happened to me. But it scares me that it will happen in production environment!

Comment: Was it like you deleted the old alias and it did not get deleted or you didn't delete the old alias in the first place? If you are not interested in giving the exact data atleast try to provide a curl recreation or a sample mapping(any simple mapping with one or two object properties) along with the routing settings. I'm sorry with the available data I can't proceed further. I can't go on with too many assumptions.